# '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'enum' string value

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have created `enum` string in Typescript like below

```
 export enum Widget {
    ICONWIDGET = "IconWidget",
};
```

But I am getting runtime error **'===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'Widget'** when I compare a string with enum string.

```
 getWidgetComponent(componentName:string) {

              if(componentName ===  Widget.ICONWIDGET){
                  return IconWidgetComponent;
              }
      }
```

I saw a similar kind of issue in reported in Github. Is there any workaround for this??

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11533

Comment: What version of TS are you using? Your code compiles fine with 2.4.1.

Comment: @Saravana 2.1.4.0 I don't have any compile error but failed in runtime

Comment: @Saravana Thanks..I Upgraded to latest and working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Upgraded to latest version of Typescript(2.4.1) and it's working fine. The previous version of Typescript I used was 2.1.4.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply assert:

getWidgetComponent(componentName:string) {

```
          if(componentName ===  (Widget.ICONWIDGET as string)){
              return IconWidgetComponent;
          }
  }
```

Comment: Two things to note here: (1) this is not a type-cast, but a type-assertion, (2) the preferred type-assertion syntax is `object as Type` instead of `<Type>object`.

Comment: I already tried both <string> and toString it's not worked for me

Comment: Thanks @John Weisz, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the enum value to string:

```
if(componentName === Widget.ICONWIDGET as string) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 enum Widget {
     ICONWIDGET = "IconWidget"
 };

 class X {

     getWidgetComponent(componentName: string) {

         if (componentName === (Widget.ICONWIDGET as string)) {
             return 'Put what you want to return here.';
         }
     }
 }     

 var x = new X();
 alert(x.getWidgetComponent("IconWidget"));
```

see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Widget%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20ICONWIDGET%20%3D%20%22IconWidget%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getWidgetComponent(componentName%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(componentName%20%3D%3D%3D%20Widget.ICONWIDGET%20as%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20new%20X()%3B%0D%0Aalert(x.getWidgetComponent(%22IconWidget%22))%3B